# Change custom entity properties programmatically with hook_entity_presave in Drupal 8

Tags: hook, drupal-8, entities

I created a custom entity with a string property `qst_type`. I would like to change this property programmatically before saving. I think you should use the `hook_entity_presave` or `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave`. Unfortunately I can not change this property with this hook.

Comment: Drupal make me crazy!
**The answer was simple:** `$entity->qst_type = 'foo';`

Comment: Post as an answer and accept it.